# statements in a for loop

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a small program which uses a for loop.

```
1 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
2 int T = sc.nextInt();
3 for(int j = 1; j < 2T-1; j+=2){
4     doSomething();
5 }
```

However, this one gives me an error.
The error message says:

```
javac Main.java -g
Main.java:12: error: ';' expected
            for(int j = 1; j < 2T-1; j+=2){
                                ^
Main.java:12: error: not a statement
            for(int j = 1; j < 2T-1; j+=2){
                                 ^
Main.java:12: error: ')' expected
            for(int j = 1; j < 2T-1; j+=2){
                                   ^
Main.java:12: error: ';' expected
            for(int j = 1; j < 2T-1; j+=2){
                                         ^
4 errors
```

I don't quite understand the 'statement' in an error message.

1) How come it produces errors?
2) What's the difference between statement and expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java isn't an algebraic math system. This

```
for(int j = 1; j < 2T-1; j+=2){
```

should be

```
for(int j = 1; j < (2*T) - 1; j += 2){
```

`2T-1` simply isn't a valid statement; variable names cannot start with a number, the compiler detects that `2` would be a valid statement and is communicating that. However, `T-1` is then in an unexpected place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
for(int j = 1; j < (2*T)-1; j+=2){
```

or

```
for(int j = 1; j < 2*T-1; j+=2){
```

Both will give you the same result.